# Defining errno values for library functions

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a small library to handle comunications with an rs232 device.

Most of the functions write a few bytes in the descriptor, wait for the reply, analise it and return:

```
int demo_function(int fd)
{
    if (sendcommand(command)==0)
    {
        if (getreply(buffer)==0)
        {
            if (buffer == ACK)
                return 0;           //Success, returns 0
            else if (buffer == NACK)
                return -1;          //Error, Nack received
            else
                return -1;          //Error, unexpected answer
        }
        else
            return -1;              //Error, Timeout
    }
    else
        return -1;                  //Error, send failled.
}
```

I wanted to follow the standard as much as possible, so i'm returning 0 on success, -1 on error. I need to define the values i should set in errno.

-Nack received: I couldn't find any error that suited this case.

-Unexpected answer: EBADMSG.

-Timeout: ETIME or ETIMEDOUT.

-Send failled: EIO ?

What error should i use for the NACK case, and are the error numbers in the other cases suitable? Or should i stay the hell out of errno and find another way for reporting the errors (like diferent return values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html) for a list of `errno`s. Personally I would stay away from `errno`, and use separate parameters etc.

In your case **the function doesn't return anything useful** so you could use the return value as an indication of success (0) or the type of error (!0).

Comment: Would you use negative or positive integers for the errors? I'm still trying to make my mind, as a few errors can be reported with further detail (write and read faillures, inside the sendcommand and getreply functions). On other hand, i probably can't cover all the faillure cases, so maybe i should stay out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably distinguish in return value between expected device answers (like ACK and NACK) and general, unexpected system failures (like timeouts, failed sends, etc.). I'd recommend returning 0 on success, 1 on NACK and -1+errno on system failures.